# Changing the Text of a TextField as the focus state changes is no longer possible since iOS 16

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Since upgrading to iOS 16 I have had numerous problems with my SwiftUI App. In iOS 15 I was able to change the text like this :

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @AppStorage("TextMin") var TextMin : String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ...
        
        TextField("Min", text: $TextMin, onEditingChanged: { (editingChanged) in
            if editingChanged {
                print("TextField focused")
                TextMin = "50"
            }
            
            else {
                print("TextField focus removed")
            }
```

The Code executes but the Text inside doesn't change (and remains blank which is the default value). Do you have any ideas why this could be?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: have you tried using: `TextField("Min", text: $TextMin).onSubmit { TextMin = "50" }`

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine I'm trying to do the opposite of .onSubmit ".onEdit". But yes .onSubmit seems to work for some reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution: iOS 15+**

```
   struct ContentView: View {
      @AppStorage("TextMin") var TextMin : String = ""
      @FocusState private var MinIsFocused: Bool
         var body: some View {

             TextField("Min", text: $TextMin)
             .focused($MinIsFocused)
             .onChange(of: MinIsFocused) { focused in
                 if focused {
                    TextMin = "Focused"
                 }
    }
```